# jQuery css('transform') returns none

Tags: jquery, transform, css-transforms

I am working on a custom design application. It has four images which have transform property attached to it due to scale and dragging position.

When I try to access this property using jQuery it returns none for the first 3 but the last one shows value though all of them have value associated with it.

In case I try out with 2 or 3 images also then also it returns the value of only last while I require for all of them.

Thanks in advance for any help on this query as I am working oon resolving this for past many days but no success.

```
<script>
function generate preview(){
var design_type=$("#block_id").val();
if((design_type=="single")||(design_type=="double")||(design_type=="three")||(design_type=="four")){
                var image1=$('#design_block_'+design_type+' #droppable1 img').attr('id');
                var img_src1=$('#'+image1).attr('src');
                var org_img_src1=$('#'+image1+'_main_image').val();
                var current_angle1=$('#'+image1+'_angle').val();
                var current_effect1=$('#'+image1+'_effect').val();
                var image_transform1=$('#'+image1).css('transform');
                alert(image_transform1);
            }

            if((design_type=="double")||(design_type=="three")||(design_type=="four")){
                var image2=$('#design_block_'+design_type+' #droppable2 img').attr('id');
                var img_src2=$('#'+image2).attr('src');
                var org_img_src2=$('#'+image2+'_main_image').val();
                var current_angle2=$('#'+image2+'_angle').val();
                var current_effect2=$('#'+image2+'_effect').val();
                var image_transform2=$('#'+image2).css('transform');
                alert(image_transform2);
            }

            if((design_type=="three")||(design_type=="four")){
                var image3=$('#design_block_'+design_type+' #droppable3 img').attr('id');
                var img_src3=$('#'+image3).attr('src');
                var org_img_src3=$('#'+image3+'_main_image').val();
                var current_angle3=$('#'+image3+'_angle').val();
                var current_effect3=$('#'+image3+'_effect').val();
                var image_transform3=$('#'+image3).css('transform');
                alert(image_transform3);
            }

            if(design_type=="four"){
                var image4=$('#design_block_'+design_type+' #droppable4 img').attr('id');
                var img_src4=$('#'+image4).attr('src');
                var org_img_src4=$('#'+image4+'_main_image').val();
                var current_angle4=$('#'+image4+'_angle').val();
                var current_effect4=$('#'+image4+'_effect').val();
                var image_transform4=$('#'+image4).css('transform');
                alert(image_transform4);
            }
}
</script>
<body>
<div id="design_block_four" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; display: inline-block; z-index: 90;">
<div style="width:49%; height:100%; float:left; border-right:2px solid #000000;position:relative;">
<div style="width:100%; height:49%; float:left; border-bottom:2px solid #000000;position:relative;">
<div style="overflow: hidden;" id="droppable1" class="drop ui-droppable"><img style="transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, -100, -53); cursor: move; transition: none 0s ease 0s ;" src="user_img/22080_work.jpg" class="dropped" id="dropped_407853"></div>
</div>
<div style="width:100%; height:50%; float:left;position:relative;">
<div style="overflow: hidden;" id="droppable2" class="drop ui-droppable"><img style="transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, -98, -113); cursor: move; transition: none 0s ease 0s ;" src="user_img/20540_work.jpg" class="dropped" id="dropped_29179"></div>
</div></div>
<div style="width:50%; height:100%; float:right;position:relative;">
<div style="width:100%; height:49%; float:left; border-bottom:2px solid #000000;position:relative;">
<div style="overflow: hidden;" id="droppable3" class="drop ui-droppable"><img style="transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, -73, -133); cursor: move; transition: none 0s ease 0s ;" src="user_img/11241_work.jpg" class="dropped" id="dropped_544668"></div>
</div>
<div style="width:100%; height:50%; float:left;position:relative;"><div style="overflow: hidden;" id="droppable4" class="drop ui-droppable"><img style="transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, -114, -115); cursor: move; transition: none 0s ease 0s ;" src="user_img/11070_work.jpg" class="dropped" id="dropped_542637"></div></div></div>
</div></body>
```

The above code has 4 img tags and all have different transform property but the javascript code returns vale for only last one and rest are returned as none.

Regards
Anoop

Comment: Please provide us with some relevant code samples.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
getComputedStyle($('[element selector]'))['-webkit-transform'];
```

Comment: it also give the same problem

Comment: maybe because there really is no value for the transform property?

Comment: If you check the sample code above in my original post you will find the transform property has value.

Comment: have you tried adding the vendor prefixes for the transform property, as in `-webkit-transform: matrix(...)`?

Comment: I have not tried that but it is not that I am not getting value but suppose there are to elements with transform then I am getting value for the last one and first one is coming none

Answer (score 0):

In my case it is because it is seen as a style attribute, so 
`$(selector).attr('style')` will return the whole style string. 
Still trying to find out why this isn't considered computed style. D3.js has the same behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Try This to get the transform property values

```
var image_transform2= $('#'+image2)[0].style.transform;
```